# How to start an intent in background and report back when it is done to display?

Tags: android, splash-screen

I am working on an app that has a blank default screen when launching it.
I want to display a splash screen, meanwhile, start the main activity **at the background**. When some process in the main activity is done, e.g. the webview is loaded, then kill the splash screen and show the main activity.

I have searched for how to implement a splashscreen, but all the examples are to delay for a few seconds then start main activity. They are all consequent.

I want to start the main activity in background until the creation and construction is done.

---

My situation is:

1. My MainActivity implements tab fragments using actionbar and pagerAdapter.
2. For each fragment, there are some webviews and asynctasks parsing json and etc,
3. While I launch the app, it firstly display a white screen with a title bar (with app icon and app name). After a few seconds, it changes to the real activity (with tabs).
4. So, I guess the white screen is the default loading screen.
5. What I want is to replace the white screen to a full screen image.

Answer (score 1):

An splash screen can be used depending upon app's requirement like:

1.Downloading data and storing it.
2.Parsing json etc

As you want to run main activity in background for this you should use AsyncTask or Service:

For example

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

String now_playing, earned;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    /**
     * Showing splashscreen while making network calls to download necessary
     * data before launching the app Will use AsyncTask to make http call
     */
    new PrefetchData().execute();

}

/**
 * Async Task to make http call
 */
private class PrefetchData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // before making http calls        

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        /*
         * Will make http call here This call will download required data
         * before launching the app
         * example:
         * 1. Downloading and storing in SQLite
         * 2. Downloading images
         * 3. Fetching and parsing the xml / json
         * 4. Sending device information to server
         * 5. etc.,
         */
        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        String json = jsonParser
                .getJSONFromUrl("http://api.androidhive.info/game/game_stats.json");

        Log.e("Response: ", "> " + json);

        if (json != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json)
                        .getJSONObject("game_stat");
                now_playing = jObj.getString("now_playing");
                earned = jObj.getString("earned");

                Log.e("JSON", "> " + now_playing + earned);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // After completing http call
        // will close this activity and lauch main activity
        Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);//Here Main activity is the splash screen.
        i.putExtra("now_playing", now_playing);
        i.putExtra("earned", earned);
        startActivity(i);

        // close this activity
        finish();
    }

}

}
```

For more information you can look onto [example to use asynctask in splash screen](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/), [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) and [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

If i understood your requirement then you should look onto **[example to use asynctask in splash screen](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/)**, once.

Process in above coding:

1. onCreate setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash); calls splash screen and **PrefetchData()** is called.
2. In **prefetch()** asynctask performs background operation in here a json is parsed from given url.
3. in **onPostExecute()** MainActivity is called . Reminder onPostExecute() is used in AsyncTask to denote that background processing is finished so in above example finish() function ends showing splash screen.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi. My MainActivity has some AsyncTasks as well. What I want is just display a full screen image while webview and asyntasks are loading. But I am using tab fragment, which does not allow me to remove the title bar, otherwise it crashes. Any ideas?

Comment: i think you should show some code and log cat error so we can understand your need clearly. Did you have look onto provided 1st link

Comment: Yes I did. But my case is a bit different. The reason I want to use loading screen is because there are lots of tasks to do when MainActivity being created. I want to show a full screen image and start loading everything of MainActivity as the same time. I have edited the original question, can you please read that again?

Comment: above code is from that link and that code does same shows splash screen till asynctask is not completed. After asynctask is completed it shows main activity. If you could only show some code of starting then we can suggest you something.

Answer (score 0):

An activity is a screen. You can't have an activity run in the background. Use [services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) or [AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead.

I don't have too much experience with splash screens since I don't develop games, but you seem to be looking for more of a loading screen rather than a splash screen. However, my guess would be that you can start an AsyncTask, give it some variable like "progress," and set a timer to check it every few seconds.

A quick search on SO for "Loading Screen" gives a lot more results.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AsyncTask` class. and override some method like-

```
onPreExecute(); //For loading splash screen
doInBackground();//For loading content-
onPostExecute();//for close splash screen & start new activty.
```